# How to bind combobox to linq result value only?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to bind combobox to value only and distinct name .But I get like this:

[image]

I want only value eg;

**Ice Box Handle,Green**

Please answer to me.My code is like this

DataTable acc= accessory.GetData();

> var query = (from t in  acc.AsEnumerable()
>
> select new
>                  {
>
> ```
>            name = t["type"].ToString(),
>
>            color = t["color"].ToString()
>
>           }).Distinct().ToList();
> ```
>
> cmbAccessoryName.DataSource = query;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ValueMember and DisplayMember property! to display inside the combo and use .Distinct() to filter duplicates!

try:

```
DataTable acc= accessory.GetData();

var query = (from t in acc.AsEnumerable()

select new {

       description=string.Format("{0},{1}",t["type"].ToString(), color = t["color"].ToString()) 

      }).Distinct().ToList();
cmbAccessoryName.DataSource = query;
```

Comment: I use .Distinct() method to distinct But I want combobox value like this Ice Box Handle,Green two value combine . How to do it?

Comment: I edit your answer like  this : var query = (from t in acc.AsEnumerable()
       orderby t["type"].ToString()
       select string.Format("{0},{1}", t["type"].ToString(),  t["color"].ToString())
      ).Distinct().ToList();                                               I get the answer.  Thanks to you.